# Remove time from datetime in spaqrl

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, rdfs

I am writing a query in `SPARQL`  and I want to compare the date value without the time. Currently, I am getting a datetime value such as `2014-08-14T13:00:00Z`. However, I want to do a filter on the date such as

```
FILTER (?date = "2014-08-15"^^xsd:dateTime)
```

I am new to SPARQL, so I need some help. Thanks.

EDITED

---

Thanks for the response guys. My apologies for the `xsd:dateTime`

```
FILTER (?date = "2014-08-15"^^xsd:date)
```

I have decided to try the following although I wanted a much 'prettier' solution.

```
FILTER (?date >= "2014-08-15T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime && ?date <= "2014-08-15T24:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
```

Comment: Beware that `"2014-08-15"^^xsd:dateTime` might not be a legal date time, even if it is a legal `xsd:date`.

Comment: Suggest using `"2014-08-15"^^xsd:date` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but not exactly the way your question asks.  The literal forms for dateTimes have to have all the fields (except the timezone), so **"2014-08-15"^^xsd:dateTime** isn't actually a legal dateTime.  See [the definition](http://%222014-08-15%22%5E%5Exsd:dateTime) for more about the date time format.

That said, it's easy enough to pull out the year, month, and day from a datetime and put them back together into a date that you can compare with other dates:

```sql
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?dt ?date where {
  values ?dt { "2011-01-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime }

  bind(xsd:date(concat(str(year(?dt)),"-",
                       str(month(?dt)),"-",
                       str(day(?dt))))
       as ?date)
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| dt                                            | date                   |
==========================================================================
| "2011-01-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime | "2011-01-10"^^xsd:date |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to include the timezone, you can do that too;  they're permitted in xsd:dates.

If you wanted to filter without creating the new date, you could also do something like

```
filter (year(?dt) = 2015 &&
        month(?dt) = 01 &&
        day(?dt) = 10)
```

That might be a fairly clean solution.

A note about your **filter**, though.  You can filter the value of a variable against a constant like you did, but that often (but not always) suggests an easier way.  For instance, instead of:

```
select ?s where {
  ?s a ?o .
  filter ( ?o = <something> )
}
```

you'd usually just use the value in place, or use **values** to specify the value of a variable:

```sql
select ?s where {
  ?s a <something> .
}
```

```sql
select ?s where {
  values ?o { <something> }
  ?s a ?o .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a simple cast to `xsd:date`, but the SPARQL engine will likely retain the time.  So it becomes a matter of parsing.  One way is to just use `SUBSTR`, as the number of characters is known:

```
FILTER (xsd:date(SUBSTR(str(?date), 0, 11)) = "2014-08-15"^^xsd:date)
```

Another is to build the date from datetime format:

```
FILTER (xsd:date(CONCAT(str(YEAR(?date)), "-", str(MONTH(?date)), "-", str(DAY(?date)))) = "2014-08-15"^^xsd:date)
```

Perhaps not as convenient given that `CONCAT` requires string conversion, but the general idea is to build the string from the datetime value and cast to `xsd:date`.

Comment: note that the substr solution (and the string concatenation that you and I both used) have a weakness in that they don't include the timezone, and timezones *are* permitted in xsd:dates.

Comment: I'm not up on all my date arithmetic, but isn't it possible that YYYY-MM-DD in one timezone could be the same date as YYYY-MM-DD+1 in another?  Preserving those timezones could be important.

Comment: Yea, that seems like a different topic, and very dependent on how the times are generated and what comparisons are needed.  One can always add the  offset to get to UTC.